# Fixed secondary Nav bar after scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, header, navbar, sticky

I was looking through some of the posts and I found most my answer however it's still not working properly for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/5n5MA/619/

The bar you see on the jsfiddle should be catching lower than the top because there is a fixed header that will be there on my main site this secondary bar is supposed to go below it.  I can get it to be fixed on jsfiddle but not on my site. And as you can see it is shrinking when it changes to fixed.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <img class="logo" src="images/headerLogo.png">
    <p class="about lighter">ABOUT US</p>
    <p class="contact lighter">CONTACT US</p>
    <img class="getStarted" src="images/getStarted.png">
</header>

<div class="mainSection1">
    <h1>SAVE TIME & MONEY</h1>
    <h2 class="lighter">CONCIERGE HAS ALL THE ANSWERS</h2>

    <p>$79.99 VALUE<br>FREE FOR YOUR CLIENTS</p>

    <img class="getStarted" src="images/getStarted.png">
</div>

<div class="subBar">
<p class="first">VALUE</p> <p class="second">SERVICES</p> <p class="third">BRANDS</p> <p class="fourth">HOW IT WORKS</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var nav = $('.subBar');
if (nav.length) {
    var fixmeTop = nav.offset().top -100;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
            $('.subBar').css({
                position: 'fixed',
                width: '100%',
                top: '73px',
                left: '0'
            });
            $('header').css(
                    'box-shadow', 'inherit'
            );
        } else {
            $('.subBar').css({
                position: 'static'
            });
            $('header').css(
                    'box-shadow', '0px 5px 9px #515151'
            );
        }
    });
}
```

css:

```
.subBar {
    background: #F1F1F2;
    height: 65px;
}

.subBar p:first-child {
    margin-left: 15%;
    border-left: 1px solid #bbbdc0;
}

.subBar p {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbbdc0;
    width: 17%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 44px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 21px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

Comment: I am a little unclear what you are asking for. I dont understand "the bar should be catching lower than the top". I do know that in order for your bar to stay the same width you can add .subBar {width: 100%;}

Comment: Update I got my bar to stay fixed. And figured out that I forgot to add width: 100 to my new CSS to prevent bar from shrinking.  But now I am wondering if anyone knows how to stop it from "snapping" into position. I want it to be smooth and I don't know what number I need to adjust.  Code Above has been edited to mach my new code.

Comment: @crazymatt I have two "headers" one that is fixed to the top of the page at all times.  and a second header that is supposed to be fixed once it touches the bottom of the first header.  So thats what I meant by "catching lower than the top" It should affix to the bottom of the top header rather than affix to the top of the page. Hope that makes more sense.  But I have solved my issue.  Now my current issue is how do you make it not jumpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been solved! I decided to make a second navbar that starts hidden than is shown when I scroll down enough.  It seems to be way less jumpy and isn't taking the original bar out of the dom (which messes with other elements below it).

Comment: if you want to consider not doing this in the future. Just define a div with no height when the item is not sticky and then give it the exact height of the item before **with width 100%**. But i'm glad you solved your problem :D

Answer (score 1):

This is because the div `.subBar` is not given any **width**.

Because of this it's width get shrinked when it's position becomes fixed, taking it to be **auto** by default.

So specify a **fixed width**. It will take that width in any position.

Also, you need to have some margin on left and right so that it stays the same as you want.

You can make the following changes:

```
.subBar {
    background: #F1F1F2;
    height: 65px;
    width:100%;
}
```

**Another more accurate solution**:
Change in the jquery

```
if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
            $('.subBar').css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '72px'

            });
        } else {
            $('.subBar').css({
                position: 'static',
                width:'auto';
            });
        }
```

Check the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5n5MA/620/).

Comment: Thanks Kunjan I did figure out the width issue myself.  However thanks for the additional tip for me. :D

Comment: Just so you know your jsfiddle doesn't work for me. But all issues have been solved.